# Print all data attributes of a JQuery object

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cytoscape

I am looking to print all data elements of a JQuery object. Here is my current code.

```
    cy.on('tap', 'node', function(evt){
      var clickedData = evt.target.attr("data");
      document.getElementById("nodeInfo").innerHTML = clickedData;
    });
```

Here is the evt.target in the console

```
Oe(1)
0: Oe [Oe(1), _private: {…}]
length: 1
_private:
active: false
animation: {current: Array(0), queue: Array(0)}
appliedInitStyle: true
arrowBounds: {source: null, target: null, mid-source: null, mid-target: null}
autoHeight: undefined
autoPadding: undefined
autoWidth: undefined
backgrounding: false
bbCache: {x1: 1090.4404404505497, y1: 155.49162695178342, x2: 1172.4404404505497, y2: 237.49162695178342, w: 82, …}
bbCachePosKey: 0
bbCacheShift: {x: 0, y: 0}
bodyBounds: {x1: 1090.4404404505497, y1: 155.49162695178342, x2: 1172.4404404505497, y2: 237.49162695178342, w: 82, …}
children: []
classes: Set(0) {size: 0}
compoundBoundsClean: false
cy: Za {_private: {…}}
data:
id: "0000_86a2e18d-ea5f-44f3-94a3-aa5cf72f8652_20211010-224514"
name: "Ryan"
type: "somnas:Person"
[[Prototype]]: Object
edges: [Oe(1)]
emitter: Ni {qualifierCompare: ƒ, eventMatches: ƒ, addEventFields: ƒ, callbackContext: ƒ, beforeEmit: ƒ, …}
grabbable: true
grabbed: false
group: "nodes"
hasPie: false
labelBounds: {all: {…}, source: null, target: null, main: {…}, sourceRot: null, …}
labelDimsKey: 1274045721130407
labelKey: -1742728187463711
labelStyleKey: 2774432038878951
listeners: []
```

You can see the data element I want printed.

Expected:
id: xxx
name: xxx
type: xxx

Result:
undefined

Comment: In a jQuery event object, `target` is **not** a jQuery object; it's a DOM reference, and thus there's no `.attr()` method.

Comment: If I use .getAttribute() I am told that is not a function. .data() and .attr() are working. I thought the same thing originally but was wrong.

Comment: Try `console.log($(evt.target).data());`

Comment: @Barmar That works! I see it in the console. Now, how to get that into an html <p></p>. Currently it prints [Object object]

Comment: Assign it to a variable and loop over it.

Comment: @Barmar Is it an array?

Comment: it's an object. The keys are the data names, the values are the values.

Comment: E.g. `{id: xxx, name: xxx, type: xxx}`

Comment: @Barmar Got it looking nice, thanks so much!

Comment: @Barmar why is it a JQuery object and not a DOM reference

Comment: Because the data is not a DOM element, it's just raw data.

Comment: It's not a jQuery object, it's just a plain object created by the jQuery `data()` method.